# Running Ingress in local using docker

Tags: docker, kubernetes-ingress

Can someone help me on how to run Ingress in my local using `Docker/Kitematic`? Not able to get this figured out.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying to accomplish? I think you need to install an *ingress controller* such as [Ambassador](https://getambassador.io) in your cluster, and that can be installed just like any other Kubernetes deployment.

An ingress controller reads ingress resources, and routes traffic to Kubernetes services/pods in your cluster based on ingress.